# CSS inheritance issues with Ember.js

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, less

I'm having issues with getting [Inspiritas](https://github.com/littke/inspiritas-bootstrap/) as an Ember app. The index.html looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>title</title>
        <meta name="author" content="me">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <link href="inspiritas.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
            <div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span3">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    {{outlet}}
                </div>
            </div><!-- /container -->
        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="dashboard">
            <div class="span9" id="content-wrapper">
                <div id="content">
                    <section id="tables">
                        ...
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
```

First off, it won't load the CSS for `<div class="container">` (not the one inside the navbar). Instead, it inherits from body.ember-application, and in the process loses all the CSS. This only happens with this container, though. The only bit of LESS I can narrow it down to is some custom styling here:

```
body > .container {
    // Color the whole container like the sidebar to fix faux columns
    background: url('images/sidebar_bg.png') repeat @sidebarBackground;

    .border-radius(@borderRadiusLarge);

    // Make some space, eh.
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Well, I've got no clue why but one class name change later its all gone to shit and everything has lost its styling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS rule you pasted uses the descendant selector, which means only elements with the `container` class that are directly below the `body` element will be styled. But when Ember inserts Handlebars templates it wraps them via a View, which creates another intermediary DIV. I'd guess that's responsible for your styles not appearing.

Comment: Lol, yeah I figured that much out, how else can I express the same thing in CSS without using the descendant selector?

Comment: Personally I would add a different identifying class other than just `container` since that is a bit too generic. If you were determined to avoid changing the HTML then you could use something like `body > .ember-view > .container` (but obviously beware that any other container at the same level, even in a different view, will match that rule).

Comment: Nice, yeah thanks for understanding, if I was to use another identifying class, I would still want it to use all of ``container``s properties, is that possible with LESS or CSS? I wouldn't mind changing the HTML to be honest, I just don't want to lose the formatting that Bootstrap already applies to it.

Comment: You can have multiple classes, so you can always leave `container` so you pick up the regular Bootstrap styles, and add `contentContainer` or whatever and then style that directly.

Comment: Pretty sure I tried something like that, I'm going to scrap the work I've done and start fresh and try like you said. Thank you :)